# Is it legal to screen scrape your own bank statements in the US?

Tags: script, legal, screen-scraping

I want to automatically download my bank statements. My bank charges monthly for [OFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Financial_Exchange) access so have considered gathering the data points by other means (scripting, screen scraping), but I want to know if it's legal in the US. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Have you thought about going to a bank that doesn't charge you a fee for a service that essentially saves them money on paper? As an aside, the screen scrape hacking exercise sounds like a fun way to circumvent corporate greed. Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an attorney and I am not giving legal advice.  But yes, the information in your monthly account statements is yours.  You can copy it however you like.